# Comparing two large CSV files to remove identical lines/records

Tags: c#, csv, compare

My need here is to compare two large CSV files with size of 4 GB each and having more than 10 Million records to get the records from New CSV file ignoring the records from old CSV file, I can't load these files into a DT or LIST and compare to find the identical records and remove them since it will give me **System.OutofMemory Exception**, so I tried another method by generating **HashCode** for each lines in CSV and formed two List's for each files then compared the two lists and identified the difference between two files.

#### Actual problem:

I know that **gethashcode()** method doesn't have enough information to get back the original string converted to hashcode, so I need some other way to generate hash code and retrieve back the actual string value from the hash value.

Following is the code I have used.

#### Generate List

```
private List<int> ListgetHashValue(string file)
        {
            try
            {                
                List<int>HashList = new List<int>();                                                                        
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {                       
                        HashList.Add(line.GetHashCode());
                    }                
                return HashList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

#### Compare List

```
List<int> result =  NewFile.Except(OldFile).ToList();
```

to get the records not in the new file list and old file list

Comment: Are the lines expected to be in the same order? Case sensitive?

Comment: You can store the line number in a dictionary keyed against the hashcode and then read that line later again

Comment: I suppose it's something you'll do once. You could use a temporary database to store your lines from the two files along with the hashcode then query to get what you want (comparing the hashcodes).

Comment: @GaneshR. no case sensitive or order criteria needed. actually i tried by adding index with a list<int> array having hashcode and index(row id) but _it is like traversing through the entire file_ for getting back the actual records for the index i got in **compare list**. is there any other way to make this efficient?

Comment: @ShanShan its a weekly repeating process. and this process will be repeated weekly. your idea sounds good but i have never thought of using BackEnd to achieve the result. ill give it a whirl.

Comment: So, it must be a process running in the middle of the night and execution speed is not a must. On the other hand, memory footprint might be an issue later (if the files gets bigger by few millions lines for example). The temporary database could be anything installed on your machine (LocalDB, SQLite...) not necessarily a sophisticated one, it's just about moving things from memory to disk. Also, if you're not bound to C#, you might want to look into [nodejs streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), it's a very efficient way to manipulate huge files/datasets with a minimal memory footprint.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to breaking down the file into multiple files and processing them asynchronously through threading but for that you need to sort the files on some parameter as the comparison should be restricted only to that file and later can merge them all.